# How to pass className as props?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

*I want to pass React.Element's className as props from component , i am new react. can i pass classname as props ? 
I am trying to achieve dynamic theme change where i can pass different props and chnage  component looks.

```
      css 
    <style>
    .c1 {
        color: red
    }
    .c2 {
        color: teal
    }

    </style>
```

```
//  code does not works 

const Comp = ( props) =>  <h1 {props.className}  > Hello , World </h1> 

ReactDOM.render(<Comp className="c1"/> , 
document.getElementById("root"))
```

```
  // but this code works 

  const Comp2 = (props) => <h1 className="c1" > Hello , World </h1> 
  ReactDOM.render(<Comp2 />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Comment: const Comp = ( props) =>  <h1 {props.className}  > Hello , World </h1> 
        ReactDOM.render(<Comp className="c1"/> , document.getElementById("root"))

Comment: why this code soes not work s

Comment: `const Comp = ( props) => <h1 class={props.className} > Hello , World </h1>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, as you are passing `className="c1"` to `Comp2` component, you just need to have a `className` attribute to hold this `props` as

```
const Comp = ( props) =>  <h1 className={props.className}  > Hello , World </h1> 


ReactDOM.render(<Comp className="c1"/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qmmmht)

Comment: i saw you code , plz change color of hello world by passing  c1 className to blue.

Comment: You can have any type of `CSS` associate with this `className`. Just you need to import the `CSS` file at right place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the dynamic classname from prop to the element as -

```
<h1 className={props.classname} > Hello , World </h1> 
ReactDOM.render(<Comp2 classname='c1'/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `className` as a `prop` just like below:

```
const Comp = props => <h1 className={this.props.className}>Hello World</h1>
```